# recyclerView showing me java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed

Tags: android

sir what is the reason for this runtime error . this error got me when recylerView scrolling down and up .how can we solve it

following exception is getting Runtime

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:769)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
            at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:500)
            at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.handleMessage(Toast.java:404)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
         Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:776)
            at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:801)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:757)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356) 
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94) 
            at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:500) 
            at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.handleMessage(Toast.java:404) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, or any new code you'd tried, would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed these older ones as duplicates of the newer one, since you have actual code there, but, in the future, please just edit the original.

Comment: can you give me answer this quetion

Comment: nobody able to answer to quetion